# Write-Output Powershell fails within RunWithElevatedPrivileges Block

Tags: powershell, runwithelevatedprivileges

This is possibly a heads-up as much as anything.

I have found that if I write a Powershell with write-output statements, they do not appear when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges

i.e

```
Write-Output "Test"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
  Write-Output "Test2"
})
```

will only output "test" to the file when run using ">"

Comment: Bit strange behavior, I am facing the same but when you use `Write-Host` it works.

Comment: Would not the `Write-Output` just return it out of the delegate (that you pass in to the `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`? As @PradipR. says, use `Write-Host`, `>` or maybee save the output in a string to print after the delegate has been executed

Comment: Yes, Write-Host works fine.  It seems to be being consumed inside the delegate as I've had odd things pop up in some other commands inside the delegate ... just thought I'd post it as a warning in case other people see strange behaviour or wonder where their output is going :-)